# Need to create SQL queries based on columns,Case when condition ,Join condition mentioned in excel sheet using python script

Tags: python

I am working for DW Etl testing projects.
Informatica jobs used to load from source tables to Target tables
My job:
As a tester i need to write  sql queries based on the columns mentioned ,join condition in excel sheet to validate the load

What I am looking for :
Is there anyway I can automate the SQl query creation by processing excel sheet via python ?

If Yes how can I do that ?

**Mapping spec excel sheet structure:**

Source     column :                   Target   column :

Table a            Firstname             Table c   Firstname
Table b            Lastname              Table C   lastname
                   concat(finame,lastna)  able C  full name

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its not very clearly defined (i.e. you could highlight sample source records and the resulting sql that you envision your automation making). That said, why use python insted of native excel functions such as concatenate ?

Comment: its not only simple concatenate.Need to provide some dynamic input using some GUI.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

i have lot of manipulation needs to be done. since python has those function features i went for python. Hence i can learn python in my technical stack.

Can i post as different question with sample query?